# Missing MVC templates in existing web project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In an existing VS2008 SP1 web project I'm introducing an MVC page. I was able to manually create a view and get it working just fine but I'm unable to get the "Add View" and "Add Controller" to work from the Solutions Explorer. Also, the MVC templates don't show up when I try and Add a New Item.

I know my VS2008 is setup properly because on a new project everything works fine (MVC templates show up in Web Items) and the "Add View" and "Add Controller" work fine as well. Is there a trick to get my legacy project to see these options.

I tried look around the csproj files. Nothing obvious there.
I see the template zip files in my folder ...Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the project type is probably set wrong. I know it did change after one of the betas.

Try this: **First, check in your existing files to source control**, in case you accidentally mess up the project file. Open both of the *.csproj files (the one that "works" and the one that "doesn't") as text. You will have to unload the projects in the IDE in order to do this. Copy the <ProjectTypeGuids> value from the one that "works" to the one that "doesn't". Now reload the projects. See if that fixes the problem.

Comment: You nailed it. It was the ProjectTypeGuids. 

I simply removed the original one and replaced it with the one this one that worked <ProjectTypeGuids>{603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
THANKS